# I keep getting the same output "You've guessed it wrong"

Tags: python, if-statement

could someone tell me if anything is wrong i keep getting "You've guessed it wrong" as my output
and how can i add number of guesses i can take

```
a=random.range(1,10)
b=input("enter a number: ") 
if a==b:print("the number you've guessed is correct") 
else:print("You've guessed it wrong")
```

Comment: You’re comparing a number with a string - try `if str(a)==b:`

Comment: You're comparing a number, `a`, with a string, `b`. Those two types never compare equal, even if one is a representation of the other. You probably want `str(a) == b`, `a == int(b)` or something similar (e.g. capturing the input with `b=int(input(...))`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the build in function `input()` always returns a string. Then later on you are comparing a string with an integer because `random.range()` always returns a string. One solution would be to turn your input into an integer as I have shown below.

```
a=random.range(1,10)
b=int(input("enter a number: "))
 
if a==b:
    print("the number you've guessed is correct") 
else:
    print("You've guessed it wrong")
```

**EDIT**
However I do suggest you put some sort of validation on that input so it does not return an error if the string cannot be changed into a int.

Answer (score 0):

you are comaparing string with integer try below code instead of yours
it will fine

```
a=random.range(1,10)
b=int(input("enter a number: "))
if a==b:
    print("the number you've guessed is correct") 
else:
    print("You've guessed it wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

`b=input("enter a number: ")`

For  you to take a number use `int()`, because `input()` accepts as string values.

Use:

`b = int(input("enter a number: "))`

And I thing you should use `random.randrange()` instead of `random.range()`